# DataLength (Transact-SQL), why this irregularity while measuring an xml file?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to see the size in bytes of an xml file.

That column is defined:

```
[XmlFile]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
```

To see the size, I did:

```
SELECT
       ...
       DATALENGTH(XmlFile) As SizeInBytes
```

I did a simple test:

```
XmlFile = 'ciao', SizeInBytes (sql): 8, Saving the file in my desktop: 4bytes
XmlFile = '', SizeInBytes (sql): 0, Saving the file in my desktop: 0bytes
XmlFile = 'TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest', SizeInBytes (sql): 176, Saving the file in my desktop: 88bytes
```

Why am I having these irregularities? Do I did something wrong? How can be sure about the correctness of the result?

Comment: `NVARCHAR` takes up twice the size as regular text (ex. `VARCHAR`) because it has the ability to store special characters, like `UNICODE` characters, which are not supported in `VARCHAR`. So, it all depends on the encoding settings you're using in the text file on your computer. If you'd use the same encoding when writing characters in the file and then saving the file, you should have approximately similar values (the db will store 2 additional bytes for offset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your data type is `NVARCHAR`.

`DATALENGTH(NVARCHAR) = 2*DATALENGTH(VARCHAR)`.

You can check this code:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH('c') -- varchar
SELECT DATALENGTH(N'c') -- nvarchar
```

Answer (score 0):

`NVarChar` stores a string in UTF-16 fashion meaning that every character takes up 2 bytes each.

`DATALENGTH` will give you the bytes occupied by the field.

You have a file length different that what you get from SQL Server because the encoding of your file is different (probably UTF-8 or ANSI). If you change the encoding in the file saving to UTF-16 you will have the same lengths.